# Conditionally adding a XElement to a new XElement using c~

Tags: c#, xelement

I am trying to use `XElement` to add new content to an existing XML data file.

For the most part it is working OK but I need to change it. This is what I have so far:

```
xdoc.Root.Add(
    new XElement("W" + record.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"),
        new XElement("Chairman", historyItem.Chairman),
        new XElement("AuxCounsellor1", historyItem.AuxCounsellor1),
        new XElement("AuxCounsellor2", historyItem.AuxCounsellor2),
        new XElement("VideoConferenceHost", string.Empty),
        new XElement("VideoConferenceCohost", string.Empty),
        new XElement("PrayerOpen", historyItem.PrayerOpen),
        new XElement("PrayerClose", historyItem.PrayerClose),
        new XElement("CBSConductor", historyItem.CBSConductor),
        new XElement("CBSReader", historyItem.CBSReader),
        new XElement("ReviewQuestion", string.Empty),
        new XElement("Items",
            new XAttribute("ItemCount", historyItem.TalkItems.Count),
            new XElement("Item",
                new XElement("Name", historyItem.TalkItems[0].Name),
                new XElement("Theme", historyItem.TalkItems[0].Theme),
                new XElement("Method", historyItem.TalkItems[0].Method)),
            new XElement("Item",
                new XElement("Name", historyItem.TalkItems[1].Name),
                new XElement("Theme", historyItem.TalkItems[1].Theme),
                new XElement("Method", historyItem.TalkItems[1].Method)),
            new XElement("Item",
                new XElement("Name", historyItem.TalkItems[2].Name),
                new XElement("Theme", historyItem.TalkItems[2].Theme),
                new XElement("Method", historyItem.TalkItems[2].Method)),
            new XElement("Item",
                new XElement("Name", historyItem.TalkItems[3].Name),
                new XElement("Theme", historyItem.TalkItems[3].Theme),
                new XElement("Method", historyItem.TalkItems[3].Method)),
            new XElement("Item",
                new XElement("Name", historyItem.TalkItems[4].Name),
                new XElement("Theme", historyItem.TalkItems[4].Theme),
                new XElement("Method", historyItem.TalkItems[4].Method)),
            new XElement("Item",
                new XElement("Name", historyItem.TalkItems[5].Name),
                new XElement("Theme", historyItem.TalkItems[5].Theme),
                 new XElement("Method", historyItem.TalkItems[5].Method)))));
```

It creates an entry like this:

```
  <W20220404>
    <Chairman></Chairman>
    <AuxCounsellor1></AuxCounsellor1>
    <AuxCounsellor2></AuxCounsellor2>
    <VideoConferenceHost></VideoConferenceHost>
    <VideoConferenceCohost></VideoConferenceCohost>
    <PrayerOpen></PrayerOpen>
    <PrayerClose></PrayerClose>
    <CBSConductor></CBSConductor>
    <CBSReader></CBSReader>
    <ReviewQuestion></ReviewQuestion>
    <Items ItemCount="6">
      <Item>
        <Name></Name>
        <Theme>“Come essere un vero amico”</Theme>
        <Method>Talk</Method>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Name></Name>
        <Theme>Spiritual Gems</Theme>
        <Method>Question and Answers</Method>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Name></Name>
        <Theme>Prepare This Month's Presentations</Theme>
        <Method>Discussion with Video</Method>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Name></Name>
        <Theme>“Chi sono i tuoi amici online?”</Theme>
        <Method>Discussion with Video</Method>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Name></Name>
        <Theme>Diamo il benvenuto agli ospiti</Theme>
        <Method>Discussion with Video</Method>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Name></Name>
        <Theme></Theme>
        <Method>Talk</Method>
      </Item>
    </Items>
  </W20220404>
```

Now, I want to add another item into this `W20220404` node, just after the list of `Items`. Eg:

```
<Teaching>
    <Name Class="0">Brother 9</Name>
    <Name Class="1">Brother 1</Name>
    <Name Class="2">Brother 3</Name>
</Teaching>
```

But:

1. I only want to add the first `Name` if `historyItem.Classes >= 1`.
2. I only want to add the second `Name` if `historyItem.Classes >= 2`.
3. I only want to add the third `Name` if `historyItem.Classes == 3`.

I can't work out how to attach that. Initially I tried extending my code:

```
new XElement("Teaching",
    new XElement("Name",
        new XAttribute("Class", 0),
        new XText(historyItem.Teaching[0])),
    new XElement("Name",
        new XAttribute("Class", 1),
        new XText(historyItem.Teaching[1])),
    new XElement("Name",
        new XAttribute("Class", 2),
        new XText(historyItem.Teaching[2])))));
```

But it doesn't factor in for the logical requirements. What is the sensible way to add this node using the rules indicated?

To summarize:

> ```
> Create the Teaching node
> if Teaching is not null
>     if historyItem.Classes >= 1
>          Add the first Name / attribute
>     if historyItem.Classes >= 2
>          Add the second Name / attribute
>     if historyItem.Classes == 3
>          Add the third Name / attribute
> ```

So if the `Teaching` element is null I want an empty `Teaching` element in XML.

Making sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `null` nodes are ignored, so make a condition where you pass `null` when the condition is not met.
Here is the basic idea:

```
new XElement("Teaching",
    historyItem.Classes >= 1 ? new XElement("Name",
        new XAttribute("Class", 0),
        new XText(historyItem.Teaching[0])) : null,
```

After reading the comment, it appears that you don't even need a conditional and could do the following:

```
historyItem.Teaching != null ? new XElement("Teaching",
    new XElement("Name",
        new XAttribute("Class", historyItem.Classes - 1),
        new XText(historyItem.Teaching[historyItem.Classes - 1]))
        ), null));
```

Comment: Thanks. So will the `Teaching` element still be created (empty) if none of the `historyItem.Classes` tests are satisfied?

Comment: Yes it will. If you do not want to create a teaching element, you need to make a condition for that as well `historyItem.Teaching != null ? new XElement("Teaching"...`. Also, I feel like you could use a loop to create these elements, but I have no idea what types of objects are `historyItem`, `Classes`, `Teaching`, so the answer is the best I could do.

Comment: I am happy to do a loop, but it is not clear to me how to go about adding the element outside of the big chain I already have. Unless this loop can also be added to the chain too? `Classes` is `int` and `Teaching` is `List<Teaching>`. BTW. I **do** want an empty teaching element if the list is null.

Comment: If I can understand this loop it would be good because that list of `Items` is also a `List` of 6 elements and could be simplified.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: I added another example. As far as I can tell, since `Classes` is an `int`, you simply need to subtract `1` to get the index in `Teaching`.

Comment: Yes, but if Classes was 0 you would end up with -1. I will have to try tomorrow.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: I see. In that case you could just check if classes is between `1` and `3`.

Comment: I also want to investigate the loop approach. I saw https://stackoverflow.com/a/21260096. For Items. I will update you tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Although I have added a second one that shows an alternative approach to acheive the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would add this as an alternative to the initial answer which goes about things slightly differently. An alternative to using one large chain and factoring in the logic requirements for the `Teaching` node:

```
XElement historyWeek = new XElement("W" + record.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));

if(historyItem.Meeting)
{
    historyWeek.Add(new XElement("Chairman", historyItem.Chairman),
        new XElement("AuxCounsellor1", historyItem.AuxCounsellor1),
        new XElement("AuxCounsellor2", historyItem.AuxCounsellor2),
        new XElement("VideoConferenceHost", string.Empty),
        new XElement("VideoConferenceCohost", string.Empty),
        new XElement("PrayerOpen", historyItem.PrayerOpen),
        new XElement("PrayerClose", historyItem.PrayerClose),
        new XElement("CBSConductor", historyItem.CBSConductor),
        new XElement("CBSReader", historyItem.CBSReader),
        new XElement("ReviewQuestion", string.Empty));

    XElement historyTalkItems = new XElement("Items",
        new XAttribute("ItemCount", historyItem.TalkItems.Count));
    foreach (var talkItem in historyItem.TalkItems)
    {
        historyTalkItems.Add(new XElement("Item",
                    new XElement("Name", talkItem.Name),
                    new XElement("Theme", talkItem.Theme),
                    new XElement("Method", talkItem.Method)));
    }
    historyWeek.Add(historyTalkItems);

    XElement historyTeaching = new XElement("Teaching");
    if(historyItem.Teaching.Any())
    {
        for (int iClass = 0; iClass < historyItem.Classes; iClass++)
        {
            historyTeaching.Add(new XElement("Name",
                new XAttribute("Class", iClass),
                new XText(historyItem.Teaching[iClass])));
        }
    }
    historyWeek.Add(historyTeaching);
}
xdoc.Root.Add(historyWeek);
```